# Finding linked elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Good day!
I have a dictionary `Dictionary<long, List<long>>` where values of List can be keys of dictionary.

What I want to do is to separate keys and values of this dictionary to set that represent linked elements. So if i have

```
dict[1] = new List<long>() { 12, 4, 2 };
dict[2] = new List<long>() { 7 };
dict[3] = new List<long>() { 25, 19, 27 };
```

I want to get as output tow sets { 1, 12, 4, 2, 7 } and { 3, 25, 19 27 };

I found a solution but it looks for me that it is not fast enough.

```
 List<HashSet<long>> graphs = new List<HashSet<long>>();
 foreach (var kv in dict)
 {
     HashSet<long> maybeNewGraph = new HashSet<long>(kv.Value);
     maybeNewGraph.Add(kv.Key);

     bool success = false;
     foreach (var hashSet in graphs)
     {
        if (hashSet.Overlaps(maybeNewGraph))
        {
            hashSet.UnionWith(maybeNewGraph);
            success = true;
            break;
        }
     }
     if (!success)
     {
        graphs.Add(maybeNewGraph);
     }
 }
```

Are there better solutions for such a problem? 
 Thank you.

**UPD** : corrected exmaple. Thanks  svick

Comment: So, if you had `1 → { 3 }, 2 → { 3 }, 3 → { 4, 5, 6 }`, then the results should be `{ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 }` and `{ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 }`?

Comment: Nope. Just {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }.

Comment: Then shouldn't your example have just one result set too? The sets have 12 in common.

Comment: Is this line valid within the Foreach statement? hashSet.UnionWith(maybeNewGraph)

Comment: Yes, why not ? I am not altering state of object that is enumerated. Just state of it's components.

Comment: I'm sceptic on this...That's not logical for me, because we can't do :  foreach (var item in lst)
            {
                item = value;

            }

Comment: But we can do foreach (var item in lst) { item.InvokeAnySetterWeWant(); }

Comment: Hmmm Ok, I think I'm gonna make this a new question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4426/discussion-between-egor-and-giant971)

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like you're trying to implement an algorithm for solving **disjoint sets**. Luckily for you, there's prior art on the web. Now I've handed you the correct search term, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) is a good place to start.

Here's a [c# implementation](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/DisjointSets.aspx). I can't vouch for its efficiency.